# How to add C++ Runtime Libraries specification (for Android NDK) in makefile

Tags: makefile, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I'm trying to use this existing library in my Android Application. It is a rather big library with a lot of code, and it's own makefile, changing all of that would be too much effort. That is why I want to adjust the Makefile so that it gets cross-compiled for Android devices.

First I want to start small and try to compile some example with this library and see if it runs on the Android device.

Here some parts that I thought are to be changed/added to the compiler and the flags:

```
CXX := ${ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAINS}/bin/clang++
CXX := ${ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAINS}/bin/clang

CFLAGS := -fPIE -fPIC -pie
CXXFLAGS := -fPIE -fPIC -pie

CXXFLAGS += --target=armv5te-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

CFLAGS += --target=armv5te-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
```

If I do not use the last two flags, compilation works, but I can only run the example on my pc, copying it to the Android device and starting it via console will give an error, that it was not compiled for this device.

So far that makes sense.

After adding the last two lines, it will abort and say:

> fatal error: 'vector' file not found

Some research says that I have to tell the ndk compiler which C++ Runtime Libraries (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html#c_runtime_libraries) it should use.

But how can I add this to my makefile? If I try to add it like it is added to Application.mk (http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html):

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Then it will still not find the vector class.

Do I have to add it differently? Is it possible to include it with just some flag?

Comment: Are you following https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html ?

Comment: @Michael you are right, it is only working with this, I was curious if it will work with those compilers Android Studios uses, but I guess it’s not. So to answer your question, no I did not use standalone toolchains in this context.